# TPM 2.0 on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, kernel, tpm

We are running one of the newest Intel NUCs with TPM 2.0 chip (what the vendor is, I haven't been able to figure out). At the moment I am just trying to load the drivers to get it visible to the system, but no dice so far

I have tried Linux Kernels 3.2, 3.16 and 4.2. According to [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.0) kernel 4.0 is when TPM 2.0 drivers were introduced.

My current steps to load drivers:

- `` ls -la /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/char/tpm `` to list available tpm drivers
- `modprobe <items from above>`. Plenty of people say that tpm_tis is the only thing they needed, but no dice for me
- Checking `/sys/class/tpm` on 4.* and `/sys/class/misc/`on 3.* for tpm0 hardware
- Running `tcsd -f` just gives me a communication error
- Triple checked the BIOS to see if TPM is enabled. It was actually enabled out of the box which apparently it isn't supposed to be?

Output of `` ls -la /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/char/tpm ``:

```
total 248
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Dec 10 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Dec 10 18:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 10 18:38 st33zp24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10984 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_atmel.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11760 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_crb.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11160 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_i2c_atmel.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14904 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_i2c_infineon.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20816 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_i2c_nuvoton.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24808 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_infineon.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66552 Nov 18 05:26 tpm.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15784 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_nsc.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31624 Nov 18 05:26 tpm_tis.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14072 Nov 18 05:26 xen-tpmfront.ko
```

Any additional steps / direction / tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I managed to get 4.4 kernel installed, it manages to load up drivers (I see tpm0 in `/sys/class/tpm/tpm0` now). But running `tcsd -f` give me the following error:

```
TCSD TDDL ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
TCSD TDDL Falling back to Read/Write device support.
TCSD TCS ERROR: TCS GetCapability failed with result = 0x1e
```

Also to make sure that I have the latest version of Trousers I compiled that from source as well, still no dice. One thing I have noticed is that inside `tpm0` there is no `pcrs` file

Comment: I did just read that Linux 4.4 may have more complete TPM 2.0 support

Comment: Yep, I've been testing 4.4 TPM 2.0 support, see https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/11/21/125 for some details on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 5):

I Think your `tpm` is working (check it with `dmesg | grep -i tpm`) but `tpm-tools` is only compatible with tpm 1.2 devices [(source)](https://sourceforge.net/p/tpmdd/mailman/tpmdd-devel/thread/CALdDubfbFeGsuJsUY70gTwf%2ByPB%2BWM8FLrcuOR%2BWrKALw2cyXg@mail.gmail.com/).

Some new projects exists, may they help us:

- IBM: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmtpm20tss/
- Intel: https://github.com/01org/TPM2.0-TSS
- TSS2 based tpm2-tools: https://github.com/01org/tpm2.0-tools

Comment: Do you know if anyone as written any good documentation for tpm2-tools yet? Or is it just what's on the Github repo for now?