# Ubuntu 16.04 - tpm-tools and trousers error during the installation

Tags: dpkg, tpm

as far as I know, I will need these two packages installed in order to communicate with the tpm module.

When I installed these two packages, I encountered the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install tpm-tools trousers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tpm-tools trousers
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 382 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3506 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package trousers.
(Reading database ... 176907 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../trousers_0.3.13-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking trousers (0.3.13-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tpm-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../tpm-tools_1.3.8-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tpm-tools (1.3.8-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up trousers (0.3.13-4) ...
Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package trousers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tpm-tools:
 tpm-tools depends on trousers; however:
  Package trousers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tpm-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 trousers
 tpm-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sudo apt-get install trousers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
trousers is already the newest version (0.3.13-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 382 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up trousers (0.3.13-4) ...
Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package trousers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tpm-tools:
 tpm-tools depends on trousers; however:
  Package trousers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tpm-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 trousers
 tpm-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

By typing `systemctl status trousers.service`

```
● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 四 2017-03-23 14:47:27 CST; 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9814 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)

 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server trousers[9814]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server tcsd[9820]: TCSD TDDL[9820]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server tcsd[9820]: TCSD TDDL[9820]: TrouSerS Falling back to Read/Write device support.
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server trousers[9814]:    ...fail!
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=30
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server systemd[1]: trousers.service: Unit entered failed state.
 三  23 14:47:27 tank-Super-Server systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The result for `journalctl -xe` is [pasted here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24233564/) it includes several errors, one of them is:

> 三  23 14:22:54 tank-Super-Server gpu-manager[3628]: Error: can't open
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/updates/dkms

How can I solve it?

Comment: [edit] your question and add  the result of  `systemctl status trousers.service` and `journalctl -xe`

Comment: great, can you also add the result of `journalctl -xe` ?

Comment: @Yaron yea, i can. however, there is too much to post it here. is there any valuable information i can provide from journalctl -xe command ?

Comment: If it is very long - you can paste the output into https://paste.ubuntu.com/ . and share the link

Comment: From your log: Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "**journalctl -xe**" for details.

Comment: @Yaron updated. thanks for letting me know the pastebin.

Comment: Odds are, you are in the same situation as I am. Our logs seem to have the same root failure. > TrouSerS ERROR: TCS GetCapability failed with result = 0x1e If you have a TPM2, tpm-tools is not what you are looking for as it does not support TPM2.
According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/770240/802619) for a related question

Answer (score 2):

It means that you don't have the TPM 1.2 cip[ installed, but you have TPM 2.0 chip.

You can't install trousers, because it needs TPM 1.2 to work.

Check your TPM version using:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm  
[    0.001234] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000A1234567 000012 (v03 ABCDEF A B C 00000001 ABC  00000000)
[    0.123456] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0x1A, rev-id 16)
```

You must install `tpm2-tools`